# How to get my files from my corrupted macOS hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

My coworker stepped on my power cable and my mac lost the power and it won't boot anymore. I have backup but I also want to save files that are not backed up yet.

I am able to remove the hard drive and mount it as an external hard drive via usb adapter on my other mac. This is what it looks like when I run: `diskutil apfs list`

```
    +-> Volume disk7s1 8F9A809C-C6F9-390D-ABFA-EB74CE62B2B4
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk7s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         208170602496 B (208.2 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk7s2 CC4FC24E-F867-4C65-ABC3-FA7AB61A866C
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk7s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         81530880 B (81.5 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk7s3 1EF908AD-47A6-4BCD-AC59-F7302F8A47FD
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk7s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         528551936 B (528.6 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk7s4 F7050FE4-9DF1-48AD-B533-465C7732B48C
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk7s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1073152 B (1.1 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk7s5 DD231F11-7C6D-439B-B2BF-6A8AE52CBEF4
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk7s5 (System)
        Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/Macintosh HD 1
        Capacity Consumed:         11347898368 B (11.3 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

When I go into "/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data" or "/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1" I wasn't able to find  `Users/aero` where my files are. I guess it needs to be mounted somehow - so where can I find these files or how can I mount `Users/aero`?

Also if I use rsync to copy all the files from the volume sudo rsync -avhPWHx '/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data' '/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data 1' only 70.04G of files can be transferred but in diskutil it says 200GB used.

There is also no Users folder under `/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data`.

```
administrator@iMac Macintosh HD - Data % ls
Applications    Library     System      Volumes     cores       home        mnt     opt     private     sw      usr
```

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1` (disk7s5) on the other hand does have a Users folder.

```
administrator@iMac Macintosh HD 1 % ls
Applications    System      Volumes     cores       etc     private     tmp     var
Library     Users       bin     dev     opt     sbin        usr
```

except it only has en empty "shared" folder inside.

[image]

I realized my drive could be corrupted beyond repairing. The reason why my User/me folder is now missing is because the drive cannot find it any longer. The picture above is done via `fsapfstools % sudo ./fsapfsinfo -H /dev/disk7`.

I tried: `sudo /sbin/fsck_apfs /dev/disk7` and `diskutil repairVolume disk7` too they both returned:

```
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by hfs_convert (748.1.47) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.120.2).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking snapshot 1 of 5 (com.apple.asr.813)
error: (oid 0x13cc1) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_oid (0xa98f3)
error: (oid 0x13cc1) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_xid (0xa6a593, expected 0xa6a5a0)
error: (oid 0x13cc1) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_subtype (0xf, expected 0xe)
error: (oid 0x13cc1) apfs_root: btn: invalid o_type (0x40000003, expected 0x3)
   Snapshot is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk7 could not be verified completely.
```

Comment: Your User files will be in `/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users`

Comment: @Allan except it is not...checkout my updated question.

Comment: I just tested a similar scenario, only adding the drive from the first one to the second one internally and my **Home** _folder_ from the first drive mounted as the second drive in another system was at: `/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/`  - I verified this by dragging a file from my **Documents** _folder_ on the second drive to **Terminal** and that's the path it started with. E.g.: `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Users/me/Documents/filename.txt`

Comment: Using the `find` _command_ from **Terminal** it reported it at: `/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/`

Comment: I realized my drive could be corrupted beyond repairing. The reason why my `User/me` folder is now missing is because the drive cannot find it any longer.

Comment: I didn't see it mentioned in your question but have you tried to repair the disk in Disk Utility? Although I have no experience with the tool, the "dd" command *may* be able to take an image of a damaged drive. Once the data is elsewhere you may be able to get to it better.

Comment: Yes I tried first aid. It failed. I am going to try dd now.

Comment: Just so people know, I tried dd and cloned my hard drive which took 16 hours. I tried first aid on the cloned hard drive and it didn't work. I still couldn't see `Users/aero`...

Comment: If they have a free trial I would try TechTool. Sometimes it repairs disks that Disk Utilities can't.  The current version is 13 but it's over $100.  I'm not recommending a $100 app but sometimes they have a free trail.